# How to formally prove that an element belongs to a sequence of sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Take any $\delta \in [ \frac{1}{2}, 1)$, I want to show that there always exists an $n$ s.t. $\delta \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1 - \frac{1}{n}) $.

Can one obtain an explicit relationship between $\delta$ and $n$ like in the case of $\epsilon / \delta$ proofs of limit statements?

Comment: sorry, I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\delta < 1 - \frac 1 n \\ 1 - \delta > \frac 1 n \\ \frac{1}{1 - \delta} < n$$
We can't divide by zero because $\delta < 1$. So let $n = 1 + \left\lceil \dfrac 1 {1 - \delta} \right\rceil$, where $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ is the ceiling.

Comment: @user73985 check what you wrote

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $\{1-\frac{1}{n}\} \rightarrow 1$, so $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists m \in \mathbb{N} : n \ge m \implies |1-\frac{1}{n}| < \epsilon$ so taking $\epsilon = 1 - \delta > 0$ gives $|1-\frac{1}{n}|<|1-\delta| \implies \delta < 1-\frac{1}{n}$

Now, to prove that $\{1-\frac{1}{n}\} \rightarrow 1$ you can do it "by hand" or use that $\{\frac{1}{n}\} \rightarrow 0$ and that $\{x_n\} \rightarrow a, \{y_n\} \rightarrow b \implies \{x_n + y_n\} \rightarrow a+b$